# Asp.net add a transparent image when mouse is over the image

Tags: asp.net, image, hover, transparent

I'm trying to add a transparent png image on top of the current image of my  item.
I used onmouseover and onmouseout. they worked great, but the problem is I want the background not change, only a highlight(transparent) image draw on it when mouseover called.

Comment: Can you show us some code what you are already done?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS or maybe just the image,set the opacity as below when the mouse is hovered over it.I guess you have that working already as you said.

```
  img { opacity: 0.3; }
```

Comment: I want to use a Png image as foreground.

Comment: I use <div> and set background property to it, also add a <asp:image> inside div and set hover cssclass that contains the hover background image url. All is fine, but size of div background image is not correct. why?